# Clarification question: Difference between solid, surface, curve, and points?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, graphing-functions

Pretty much what the title of this question says. Very confused about how these 4 things differ themselves from each other. Furthermore, how do they differ with regards to **boundaries**? Does anybody have some intuitive explanation?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In short: [dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension) ($3$ for a solid, $2$ for a surface, $1$ for a curve, $0$ for a point).